# BeautifulSoup: "TypeError/AttributeError: 'NoneType'"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://joboutlook.gov.au/A-Z'

r = requests.get(url)
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')

urls = []
h4s = soup.find_all('h4')
for h4 in h4s:
    a = h4.find('a')
    print(a)
    href = a['href']
    print(href)
    new_url = f'https://joboutlook.gov.au/{href}'
    print(new_url)
    urls.append(new_url)
urls
```

The prints all work. (a) shows all the 'a' tags, (href) shows all the hrefs, (new_url) shows all the new urls!

And yet I keep getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`, and nothing is added to the urls list.

If I change it to `a.get('href')` it says: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

(It's not actually Google, just fyi)

It's probably something simple, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the source url to re-create the problem.

Comment: Updated the URL

Comment: what's the start url you base soup off?

Comment: https://joboutlook.gov.au/A-Z

Comment: Looks like one of the `h4` doesn't have an `a` tag. This is giving the error. Just try use a try-except block.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I didn't think to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to using a selector which filters on `h4` having child element with `href` attribute.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://joboutlook.gov.au/A-Z')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
links = [f'https://joboutlook.gov.au/{item["href"]}' for item in soup.select('h4 > [href]')]
```

You could make the assumption all `a` tags have `href` (slighty faster and less robust but likely fine)

```
links = [f'https://joboutlook.gov.au/{item["href"]}' for item in soup.select('h4 > a')]
```

Comment: Great idea! Didn't think about using `select`

Answer (score 1):

Provide if condition,if anchor tag available then get the `href` and append it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://joboutlook.gov.au/A-Z").text,'html.parser')
urls = []
h4s = soup.find_all('h4')
for h4 in h4s:
    a = h4.find('a')
    if a:
     href = a['href']
     #print(href)
     new_url ='https://joboutlook.gov.au/{}'.format(href)
     #print(new_url)
     urls.append(new_url)

print(urls)
```